# Escaping foward slash problems

Tags: powershell

In the following semi-pseudo code, the forward-slash of the first element in the array `$system` is always read as a back-slash.

I have tried the various escape characters such as ` and \ but to no avail. Is this a known problem in PowerShell? How to solve?

```
$system = @("Something/Anything", "Super Development","Quality Assurance")

//the following is looped with $y
$string| ConvertTo-json | FT | Out-File -append C:\Test\Results\$($system[$y])_All.csv

//error:
Message        : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Test\Results\Something\Anything_All.csv'
```

Comment: In Windows you can not use "/" in the file naming!

Comment: `$something[$y]` doesn't seem to resolve anything for me  
`$something = 'test-'
foreach ($y in $system){
$something[$y]
}`

Comment: @HiteshDhruna sorry, typo. fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@autosvet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125723/escaping-foward-slash-problems#comment65597308_39125723) already mentioned in the comments to your question there are several [reserved characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions) that can't be used in filenames/paths on Windows, namely:

> - Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:
>
>   The following reserved characters:
>
>   - `<` (less than)
>   - `>` (greater than)
>   - `:` (colon)
>   - `"` (double quote)
>   - `/` (forward slash)
>   - `\` (backslash)
>   - `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
>   - `?` (question mark)
>   - `*` (asterisk)

These characters can't be escaped, only replaced. You can use the [`GetInvalidFileNameChars()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for programmatically determining the characters that need to be replaced:

```
$invalid = [regex]::Escape([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars())
$string | ConvertTo-json | FT |
  Out-File -Append C:\Test\Results\$($something[$y] -replace $invalid, '_')_All.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint on my deleted question Ansgar. I didn't noticed that these are all names for the CSV...